# Restkit metadata isn't mapping

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm struggling to get proper mapping with metadata... Everything maps perfectly except metadata url parameters.

Here's my Entity Mapping :

```
RKEntityMapping *statisticsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Statistics" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[statisticsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"fromDate", @"toDate", @"visits", @"newVisits"]];
[statisticsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"@metadata.routing.parameters.randomId" : @"applicationRandomId"
                                                        }];
[statisticsMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"application" connectedBy:@"applicationRandomId"];
```

Response descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *ststResp = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:statisticsMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"api/apps/:randomId/statistics"
                                                                                       keyPath:@"details"
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Routing:

```
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Statistics class] pathPattern:@"api/apps/:randomId/statistics" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
```

And how I get them:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/apps/%@/statistics",applicationRandomId];
NSMutableURLRequest *statistics = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:@"Statistics" method:RKRequestMethodGET path:url parameters:@{
                                                                                                                                                         @"fromDate" : @"01-01-2016",
                                                                                                                                                         @"toDate" : @"20-01-2016"
                                                                                                                                                         }];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:statistics managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {     

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

I also tried mix with variety of Routes and getObjectsAt etc...

Regards, Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"statistics" pathPattern:@"api/apps/:randomId/statistics" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:@"statistics" object:@{@"randomId" : applicationRandomId} parameters:nil
                                                                                                     } success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                                                                                     } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                                                                                     }];
```

Eh didn't know it works that way.